# Change audio output device

Tags: python, pyaudio

How can I change the speaker output via pyaudio?
For example, I want the sound from my computer speaker to be transferred to my headphones.

what ı have so far

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyaudio

# Create a Tkinter window
window = tk.Tk()

# Create an instance of PyAudio
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Get the available audio outputs
audio_outputs = []
for i in range(audio.get_device_count()):
    output = audio.get_device_info_by_index(i)
    audio_outputs.append(output)

def change_audio_output():
    # Get the index of the selected audio output
    selected_index = audio_output_listbox.curselection()[0]
    selected_output = audio_outputs[selected_index]

    # Change the default audio output
    audio.set_default_output_device(selected_output['index'])

# Create a listbox to display the available audio outputs
audio_output_listbox = tk.Listbox(window)
for output in audio_outputs:
    audio_output_listbox.insert(tk.END, output['name'])

# Create a button to change the default audio output
change_output_button = tk.Button(window, text='Change Default Audio Output', command=change_audio_output)

# Pack the widgets into the window
audio_output_listbox.pack()
change_output_button.pack()

# Start the main loop
window.mainloop()
```